# MPI_Bcast inside an if statement

Tags: c, parallel-processing, mpi, distributed, openmpi

### 1. Goal

Let's suppose we have `world_size = 4` processors disposed as a topological `mesh`:

```
P0-P1
|  |  
P2-P3
```

where `-` represents `mesh_r` (mesh_rows) communicator and `|` represents `mesh_c` (mesh_columns) communicator, build through `build_mesh` procedure.

My goal is distribute `P0` and `P3` element called `A_loc` respectively to `P1` and `P2` (in general, from processors on the diagonal of the `mesh` to the ones on their rows).

I used an additional `A_loc_add` variable because I must not re-write `A_loc` variable during these distributions.

### 2. My code

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int process_rank, world_size;
    int mesh_rows, mesh_columns;
    int mesh_dimension = 2;
    int *process_coordinates;
    MPI_Comm mesh, mesh_r, mesh_c;
    int process_rank_mesh;
    int *A, *A_loc;
    int m, n, mloc, nloc;

    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &process_rank);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &world_size);

    if (process_rank == 0) {
        m = n = 2;
    }

    MPI_Bcast(&m, 1, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    MPI_Bcast(&n, 1, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    A = fill_matrix(A, m, n);

    if (process_rank == 0) 
        mesh_rows = 2;

    if (is_divisible(world_size, mesh_rows))
        mesh_columns = world_size / mesh_rows;
    else {
        mesh_rows = 1;
        mesh_columns = world_size / mesh_rows;
    }
   
    MPI_Bcast(&mesh_rows, 1, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    MPI_Bcast(&mesh_columns, 1, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    process_coordinates = (int*) calloc(mesh_dimension, sizeof(int));
    build_mesh(&mesh, &mesh_r, &mesh_c, process_rank, world_size, mesh_rows, mesh_columns, process_coordinates);
    MPI_Comm_rank(mesh, &process_rank_mesh); 
 
    mloc = m / mesh_rows;
    nloc = m / mesh_columns;

    handle_errors(m, n, world_size, process_rank);

    A_loc = (int*) calloc(mloc * nloc, sizeof(int));
    distribute(A, A_loc, m, n, mloc, nloc, world_size, mesh_rows, mesh_columns);

    int *A_loc_add = (int*) calloc(mloc * nloc, sizeof(int));
    memcpy(A_loc_add, A_loc, sizeof(A_loc) * mloc);
    // process_rank is the processor rank in MPI_COMM_WORLD
    // so I choose P0 and P3 (the ones on the diagonal)
    // but they have rank 0 and 1 in mesh_r
    if (process_rank == 0)
        MPI_Bcast(A_loc_add, mloc * nloc, MPI_INT, 0, mesh_r);
    else if (process_rank == 3)
        MPI_Bcast(A_loc_add, mloc * nloc, MPI_INT, 1, mesh_r);

    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}

void distribute(int *Mat, int *Mat_loc, int m, int n, int mloc, int nloc, int world_size, int mesh_rows, int mesh_columns)
{
    MPI_Datatype square_block;
    int stride = n;
    int count = mloc;
    int block_length = nloc;
    MPI_Type_vector(count, block_length, stride, MPI_INT, &square_block);
    MPI_Datatype square_block_resized;
    MPI_Type_create_resized(square_block, 0, sizeof(int), &square_block_resized);
    MPI_Type_commit(&square_block_resized);
    int *send_counts = (int*) calloc(world_size, sizeof(int));
    int *displs = (int*) calloc(world_size, sizeof(int));
    for (int i = 0; i < mesh_rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < mesh_columns; j++) {
            send_counts[i * mesh_columns + j] = 1;
            displs[i * mesh_columns + j] = i * n * block_length + j * block_length;
        }
    }
    
    MPI_Scatterv(Mat, send_counts, displs, square_block_resized, Mat_loc, mloc * nloc, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
}

void handle_errors(int m, int n, int world_size, int process_rank)
{
    if (process_rank == 0) {
        if (m != n) {
            perror("Not square matrices\n");
            MPI_Abort(MPI_COMM_WORLD, EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        if (world_size != 4) {
            perror("World size must be 4\n");
            MPI_Abort(MPI_COMM_WORLD, EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }
}

bool is_divisible(int dividend, int divisor)
{
    return dividend % divisor == 0;
}

void build_mesh(MPI_Comm *mesh, MPI_Comm *mesh_r, MPI_Comm *mesh_c, int process_rank, int world_size,
    int mesh_rows, int mesh_columns, int *process_coordinates) 
{
    int mesh_dimension = 2;
    int *mesh_n_dimension;
    int mesh_reorder = 0;
    int *mesh_period;
    int *remain_dims = (int*) calloc(mesh_dimension, sizeof(int));
    mesh_n_dimension = (int*) calloc(mesh_dimension, sizeof(int));
    mesh_n_dimension[0] = mesh_rows;
    mesh_n_dimension[1] = mesh_columns;
    mesh_period = (int*) calloc(mesh_dimension, sizeof(int));
    mesh_period[0] = mesh_period[1] = 0;
    MPI_Cart_create(MPI_COMM_WORLD, mesh_dimension, mesh_n_dimension, mesh_period, mesh_reorder, mesh);
    MPI_Cart_coords(*mesh, process_rank, mesh_dimension, process_coordinates);
    remain_dims[0] = 0;  
    remain_dims[1] = 1;
    MPI_Cart_sub(*mesh, remain_dims, mesh_r);
    remain_dims[0] = 1;
    remain_dims[1] = 0;
    MPI_Cart_sub(*mesh, remain_dims, mesh_c);
}

int *fill_matrix(int *Mat, int m, int n)
{
    int k = 0;
    Mat = (int*) calloc(m * n, sizeof(int));
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) 
            Mat[i * n + j] = ++k;
    return Mat;
}
```

### 3. Result

I get `1,2,3,4` instead of `1,1,4,4`:

```
P0 A_loc_add:
1 

P1 A_loc_add:
2 (exp. 1)

P2 A_loc_add:
3 (exp. 4)

P3 A_loc_add:
4
```

Comment: Shouldn't mesh contain connections such that each node is connected to each other node? What about P0<->P3 and P1<->P2?

Comment: @kiner_shah No, it does not.

Comment: check the size of the `mesh_r` communicator. I guess it is `2`, so `root` can only be `0` or `1`.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet Hello. `mesh_r` size is `2`. Is there something wrong with `build_mesh` procedure?

Comment: you are making the same mistake you made in a previous question: you think globally when you should think from the point of view of each MPI task. Globally, there is one variable called `mesh_r` but there are two disjoint communicators. locally, each task is part of its `mesh_r` communicator.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet Yes, I noticed now. If I `if (process_rank == 2) printf("%d-",ranks[I]);` it prints correctly 2-3. But how can I exploit this communicator so I can solve my problem MPI_ERR_ROOT invalid root?

Comment: think locally! `P2` has rank `2` in `MPI_COMM_WORLD` made of `{0,1,2,3}`, but it has rank `0` in `mesh_r` made of `{0,1}` in `mesh_r` e.g. `{2-3}` in `MPI_COMM_WORLD`.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet I tried `for (int i = 0; i < mesh_rows; i++) for (int j = 0; j < mesh_columns; j++) if (i == j) MPI_Bcast(A_loc_add, mloc * nloc, MPI_INT, i, mesh_r);` but `P2` receives `3` instead of `4`

Comment: which `root` did you use for `mesh_r={P2,P3}` ?

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet Please check out I update my post

Comment: your program can crash because `mesh_row` is used uninitialized on ranks > 0.
`MPI_Bcast()` is a collective operation and must hence be invoked by *all* the ranks of the communicator, and this is not the case here.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet How can I solve? The only idea I had is that one I have written

Comment: "`MPI_Bcast()` is a collective operation and must hence be invoked by all the ranks of the communicator" this means I cannot put it in an `if`-statement. But if I remove the `if`-statement I would get: `MPI_Bcast(A_loc_add, mloc * nloc, MPI_INT, 0, mesh_r);` which broadcasts P0 and P2's `A_loc_add` to every processors in their rows. So P0: 1, P1: 1, P2: 3, P3: 3. But I need to broadcast P0 _and_ P3 variables, not P0 and P2! How can I pick P0 _and_ P3?

Comment: look for the function `f` such as `f(0)=f(1)=0` and `f(2)=f(3)=1`, and then simply use `root=f(process_rank)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved implementing a function such that `f(0) = f(1) = 0` and `1` otherwise, as suggested by Gilles.